# Does Django checks if a QuerySet has already been evaluated?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I couldn't find a way to print out when Django is actually hitting the database from a QuerySet method, but according to the docs, my example below should unnecessarily perform two queries, or does it?

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
#Slicing evaluates a query
queryset = queryset[5:10]
#Serializing should also evaluate a query
data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset, fields=('pk', 'name'))
```

Comment: Why should that perform two queries? Of course, if a query has already been evaluated, Django does not need to evaluate it again.

Comment: And you can print out what queries Django is making by accessing `django.db.connection.queries` - see the [FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) - or using the django-debug-toolbar.

Comment: Run Django with the environment variable `DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG` set!

Comment: Take a look at this docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets .

Comment: Where in the docs does it say this should perform two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that this code would do more than one query would be if the serializer includes data about a related field then a further query may be done in order to retrieve results for the related model.

As noted by [knbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615075/knbk) in the comments,

> Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated also returns a list.

Since you're not using a step, the slicing isn't the operation that evaluates the query

Comment: _"Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated also returns a list."_ ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)). Slicing an unevaluated queryset without a `step` does not evaluate it. In the OP's example, only serializing the (sliced) queryset will evaluate it.

Comment: @knbk - oh thanks i misread that part of the docs on slicing (or forgot it). Ill delete this answer since im not somewhere where im able to edit/fix it atm